# Fetching Table from MySQL using PHP and using a Button to Update?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to create an admin system wherein the list of accounts will be displayed and under a column called "account status", I like to place a button which shows "ACTIVATE" if the fetched account status is Inactive (I have done it using Boolean wherein 1 is active and 0 is inactive).

However, I can't make the displayed button update the specific row wherein it is placed and I tried using an Update query which doesn't work. Is my idea possible or I have to resort to manual update using inputting of textfields? Hope you can help me as I'm new to PHP.

Here's my code:

```
    <?php
//FETCH DATA
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts");
    while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

                $accountupdate = $fetch["accountid"];

                echo" <tr>
                <td><font face='verdana,arial' size=-1>".$fetch["accountid"]."</td>
                <td><font face='verdana,arial' size=-1>".$fetch["username"]."</td>
                <td><font face='verdana,arial' size=-5>".$fetch["password"]."</td>
                <td><font face='verdana,arial' size=-1>".$fetch["firstname"]."</td>
                <td><font face='verdana,arial' size=-1>".$fetch["lastname"]."</td>                  
                <td><font face='verdana,arial' size=-1>".$fetch["email"]."</td>
                <td><font face='verdana,arial' size=-5>".$fetch["salt"]."</td>";

                    if($fetch["account_status"] == 0){
                        echo "<form action='' method='post'>
                             <td><input type='submit' name='activate' value='Activate'></td>
                             </form>";
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "<td><font face='verdana,arial' size=-1>".$fetch["account_status"]."</td>";
                    }
    }

if (isset($_POST['activate'])){
    mysql_query("UPDATE accounts SET account_status=1 WHERE accountid='$accountupdate'") or die(mysql_error());
    header("Location:admin_accounts.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: after submit your $accountupdate variable is probably lost. try to post that value too inside form (for example using hidden field)

Comment: @ Vlad Preda: Thanks, however, I'm using an older system, this is just a small project and we are required to use mysql functions :(. My problem is, I can't find any archived questions similar to mine.

Comment: You need to pass ID of row which needs to be updated and capture that value into variable $accountupdate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a hidden field with the id to be updated to your form:

```
if($fetch["account_status"] == 0){
    echo "<form action='' method='post'>
        <td><input type='submit' name='activate' value='Activate'>
        input type='hidden' name='upd_id' value='{$fetch['accountid']}'</td>
        </form>";
}
```

then after submit, read the id from the hidden field:

```
if (isset($_POST['activate'])){
    mysql_query("UPDATE accounts SET account_status=1 WHERE accountid='{$_POST['ups_id']}' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
    header("Location:admin_accounts.php");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll update my code and comment if it works. Btw, what does Limit to 1 do?

Comment: @JerickDilla: `LIMIT 1` limits the UPDATE to 1 row, which is what you want. I set it for safety, if my WHERE-condition would ever match more than 1 row, oly 1 would be affected.

Comment: Oh I see.Thanks it works like a charm! Man, hope I get used to this and maybe consider MySQLi in the future :D

Comment: @JerickDilla: Glad I could help. if migrating from mysql_*, I'd recommend going to PDO...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using several forms you can use hyperlinks.Its needs little bit of code change

```
<td><input type='submit' name='activate' value='Activate'></td>
 TO 
 <td><a href='yourfilename.php?acctid='.$accountupdate >Activate</a></td>


      if (isset($_POST['activate'])){
      TO
      if (isset($_GET['acctid'])){
     $acctid = $_GET[acctid];
     mysql_query("UPDATE accounts SET account_status=1 WHERE accountid='$acctid '")         or
```

die(mysql_error());
          }

Finally as suggested change the code to mysqli* :-)

Comment: Thanks! Well, I'm choosing the button method or is it a bad thing to have many forms? I'll consider this option if the need arises.

Comment: NOthing like that..What ever is understandable and easy for you, just stick to it :) ..

If you using forms you have to maintain the hidden fields and based on that you have to update the value. If you got it just go with forms.